# Addition of Doubles in C# application producing strange results

Tags: c#

I've read quite a bit on floating points and rounding errors, but I haven't found anything specific to my problem.

Here's what happens

I add 15.95 and then 15.95 and the number becomes 31.9 (without a zero at the end). Then when I add 19.95 it becomes 51.849999999999994. What is causing this to happen? If I need to provide actual code I can do so. Thanks!

Comment: That you're asking this question would imply you haven't read *anything* about floating point structures or their resulting rounding errors, contrary to your statement that you have done so.

Comment: Welcome to floating-point arithmetic. Enjoy your stay.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Are the doubles explicitly that type, or are they being implicitly treated as `float`?

Comment: This is a classic rounding error associated with floating point numbers. Do some more reading on the subject.

Comment: Would it be cool if someone told me how to fix this?

Comment: Easiest fix is to use a `decimal` instead

Comment: Note that that won't fix *all* rounding errors.  E.g., you can't express `10 / 3` exactly in decimal.  But you can express `0.95` exactly.

Comment: You can't _fix_ something that works as expected.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Works as *designed*, maybe.  Clearly the OP *expected* 51.85

Comment: @I4V Thank you for stepping down to my level and offering something constructive, man. I'll try changing it to decimal.

Comment: @Fitzpleasure In the future you should actually do some research before asking questions.  When you choose not to do even the most basic research before asking a question about a *very* common problem there is very little incentive for anyone to spend their time and effort helping you.  When you've done your own homework first, and demonstrate that you've done so, you'll find that the community is *much* more helpful.

Comment: [Read this](http://floating-point-gui.de/).  No, I'm serious, [**Read this**](http://floating-point-gui.de/).  Whoever you are, you really, *really* need to [***Read this***](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: off-topic? Are you guys serious?

Comment: Double is a [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) in .NET and, as I'm sure you've read, certain fractions cannot be expressed in binary (just like 1/3 can't be expressed in decimal) which is why you're getting these rounding errors.  If you need a naturally exact decimal then I would recommend you use the [Decimal type](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Quibblesome *"must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results"*

Comment: All I see is someone asking a programming question that people are happy to answer and explain but a bunch of librarians stating its "off-topic" and closing it. The rule book means nothing to me in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, this is because some base-10 numbers (like 0.9) cannot be represented in base 2 in a finite number of digits, just like the fraction 1/3 cannot be represented in base 10 in a finite number of digits (you get 0.333...).

0.9 converted to base 2 is 0.1110011001100..., and this binary representation gets truncated such that the result is as number *close to* 0.9 (base 10) but is *slightly* smaller.

Note that you will *not* see this behavior with the number 0.9, as the float will have a coefficient of 9 and a mantissa of -1.  But you *will* see it with 31.9, as it will have a coefficient of 3.19 (in base 2 = `11.00>11000010100011110101<`, repeating section between the `><` marks) and a mantissa of +1.

Comment: Excellent post!  I totally had to [look up mantissa](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+mantissa&oq=define+mantissa&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3362j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) :-)

Comment: I wonder why `31.9` has a coefficient of `3.19` with mantissa of `+1` but not `319` with mantissa of `-1`?

Comment: @KingKing Because that's how floating point numbers work.  The number is multiplied by a positive or negative power of 10 such that the first significant digit in the number moves into the ones' place.  The negative of that power becomes the mantissa.  (0.00345 * 10^3 = 3.45, so 3.45 is the coefficient and -3 is the mantissa.)  Then it all gets converted to binary.